# Docker Registry vs Docker "Trusted" Registry

Tags: docker, docker-datacenter, dtr, docker-ucp

I just read the entire docs on [securing a private Docker Registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/). In addition to this, there seems to be a "Docker **Trusted** Registry", which is [described](https://docs.docker.com/docker-trusted-registry/) as:

> Docker Trusted Registry (DTR) lets you run and manage your own Docker image storage service, securely on your own infrastructure behind your company firewall.

Furthermore, the doc goes on to list a DTRs features:

- An image registry to store, manage, and collaborate on Docker images
- Pluggable storage drivers
- Configuration options to let you run DTR in your particular enterprise environment.
- Easy, transparent upgrades
- Logging, usage and system health metrics

**But doesn't the "normal" Docker Registry give me these as well?!?**

Are these two things really the same, or is DTR some sort of commercialized offering of a Docker Registry? Or something else? I'm so confused!

Comment: Now the Docker Registry is deprecated and the new Docker Distribution is out written completely in GoLang.
https://github.com/docker/distribution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

DTR is the paid support service for the registry - see https://hub.docker.com/enterprise/

Basically, they help you setup and will give you support down the road. It might have some niceties, otherwise you are left to your own to figure out how to run the registry.

Answer (score 11):

New features in Docker Trusted Registry are:

- Control access and permissions by user or organisation
- Web UI to search and browse repos, manage users and setting
- Integrate to CI and CD systems to automate workflows
- LDAP/AD integration
- Flexible storage
- support User audit logs
- Soft Delete image tags
- Garbage collection

Comment: Are these features not available when we setup private docker registry?